# How to disable when checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, checked

I have few jQuery tags in one page for sample…

```
Js/jquery.js
Js/jquery-2.js
Js/jquery-3.js
```

Due to crashed each other at the same time and won’t work to use all of those .js tags same time.

I have created 3 checkboxes like this…

```
<input name="jquery" type="checkbox" value="jquery">
<input name="jquery-2" type="checkbox" value="jquery-2">
<input name="jquery-3" type="checkbox" value="jquery-3">
```

What I like to have is when checked any of those checkbox and is become disable, so for sample…. I checked for jquery and jquery-2, and leave un-check jquery-3.

My question is that how can write code to **disable jquery from the file** when checked.

Many thanks.

Comment: You cannot simply disable a library once loaded, without simply removing its reference like: `jQuery = {}`. You may want to consider using an MVC framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the checkboxes to behave in a group (selecting 1 unchecks all others), you can do something like:

```
let checkBoxes = $("[name^=jquery]")

// Listen to changes on all checkBoxes, ignore the current element and uncheck all else
// Make sure to use jQuery 1.6+
checkBoxes.change(function(e) {
    const me = this;
    checkBoxes.not(me).prop('checked', false).removeAttr('checked')
})
```